# (v2.90) What are these thicker blue lines, and how do I quickly remove them?

Tags: edges

I can manually remove them by deleting the surrounding faces and remaking them, but there's got to be a faster way.

I get these lines after joining <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> two separate objects (e.g. two mirrored halves of the body via Duplicate + Scale by -x) and they don't always appear at the fusion points. I'd thought they meant duplicated vertices, but merging them <kbd>M</kbd> at center doesn't do anything. Could it be a duplicated edge, though?

If it means anything, the horizontal thick-line was a former UV seam.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those edges are marked "sharp". To remove, select all (or just the ones you want to clear) in edit mode and then select "clear sharp".

[image: Sharp]

Comment: So simple, haha. Thank you! How do these sharp edges result, though?

Comment: You mean how do they get there? I'm not sure what the hotkey (shortcut) is, but you can mark them sharp from the same menu. As for it's use - it's commonly used with an Edge Split modifier to specify custom splits.

Comment: I see. I'll have to play with Blender more to know when best to use them, though I was mainly wondering why those sharp edges appear automatically/randomly when I Join two meshes. Maybe just Blender things.

Comment: I'm not sure then. It shouldn't happen by default, I don't think. I was assuming you're using custom colors for blender, and that is why your wireframe is the same blue color, but now i'm wondering is it possible that _every_ edge on the mesh is set as sharp (hence the blue color), and when you join them, the thicker line is because you have 2 edges on top of one another? If so, try pressing M (merge) and selecting "by distance" to see if that does anything.

Comment: Doing that on Vertex View (so only one point of an edge selected, though I did use circle on wireframe view to select every point that might be clustered in that area) did nothing, but I'll be sure to try that on Edge mode on the next model that gives me that glitch. Thank you!